# error compiling inline assembly with gcc, "shl"

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

this is the actual code that I'm trying to convert to gcc style asm inline assembly code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int reverse(int num);

int main(){
    int num;
    cout << "enter number: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;
    cout << reverse(num);
    return 0;
}

int reverse(int num){
    if(num == 0 || num == 1){
        return num;
    }
    __asm
    {
        xor eax, eax
        xor ecx, ecx     
        mov ebx, num    
        clc             ; clear carry
not_found:
        inc ecx
        shl ebx, 1
        jnc not_found


        rcr eax, 1
        mov edx, ecx
again:
        shl ebx, 1
        rcr eax, 1
        inc ecx
        cmp ecx, 32
        jne again

        dec edx     
again2:     
        shr eax, 1
        dec edx
        cmp edx, 0
        jne again2
    }

}
```

As i was unable to compile the above code with gcc, I tried converting it to some thing that could be compiled successfully by a gcc compiler, but so far I could not manage to produce any meaningful result.

Comment: Can you give more context for this snippet (declaration of temp,num). It compiles fine for me,.

Comment: Not an assembly wizard but I see two `l` in `shll`, which probably means this is the `long int` version, what's the type of `num` **exactly** ?

Comment: Also giving your architecture may be helpful.

Comment: Yeah it compiles fine both 32 and 64 bit for me too. Of course this is horrible abuse of inline asm, I sure hope eventually it will be more meaningful code. Also note `clc` there has no effect since `shl` doesn't read carry.

Comment: @Jester, Bo: You are being uncharitable. I assume this is a code snippet.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: `l`-suffix in x86 assembly means 32-bit.  `q` means 64-bit and `w` means 16-bit.  These are independent of the sizes the C compiler uses for int or long.

Comment: int reverse(int num){
 if(num == 0 || num == 1){
  return num;
 }
 int temp = 0;
    asm(...);
    return temp;
    }
I actually want to include some assembly code that compiles fine with Microsoft Visual Studio, but when I compile it with gcc, following the ATT style, I get compile time error on using shl, rcr, all with operand type mismatch.To my assembly code, I intend to give num as input, and temp as output.I'd be using eax,ebx,ecx,edx registers in the complete picture.The code only depicts a snippet that I'm using to remove (debug) these compile time errors with GCC (4.7.2).

Comment: @Bo: I think you must have misunderstood me. The OP has posted a fragment of code (a code snippet) that was never intended to be a working program. Presumably the finished version will do more than just `num <<= 1`.

Comment: If by `reverse` you mean reverse the bits, you can certainly imlement that in C just fine. Side note, reverse of `1` isn't gonna be `1`. Could you specify what you are trying to achieve, and also post code that is compilable and actually fails like you say, because we have been able to compile this fragment (guessing the missing stuff) without problem.

Comment: That code snippet makes no sense; for one, it has only a single operand `(num)` and never retrieves/sets its output anywhere. Second, the syntax is at the very least questionable in two ways - it uses semicolons as line separators instead of newlines (not all assemblers will accept that), and second, it specifies the registers in the clobber list with `%` prefix - which isn't what `gcc` normally groks.

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int reverse(int num);

int main(){
 int num;
 cout << "enter number: ";
 cin >> num;
 cout << endl;
 cout << reverse(num);
 return 0;
}

int reverse(int num){
 if(num == 0 || num == 1){
  return num;
 }
 int temp = 0;
 asm(
  " movl %1, %%ebx  \n\t"
  "  clc     \n\t"
  " shl %%ebx, 1      \n\t"
        : "=r"(temp)
        : "r"(num)
  : "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx");

 return temp;
}

the above is the code that I'm unable to compile so far, I've made the changes according to FrankH's suggestions, still no luck.

Comment: Now THAT doesn't compile. Notice it has `shl %%ebx, 1` and not `shll $1,%%ebx` as in your question. Also, even though you claim you have followed FrankH's advice, you still don't set the output.

Comment: @user1949229 That looks horrible as a comment :) I've put that in your question.

Comment: thank you FrankH, Jester, @hvd i was able to convert my code and compiled it successfully !! 
Additionally, can you also help what's wrong with doing 
shrl %%edx, %%eax ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code in the comment of the OP, here is a modified example that shifts by one bit using inline assembly:

```c++
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int reverse(int num);
int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "enter number: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << endl;
    cout << reverse(num) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int reverse(int num)
{
    if (num == 0 || num == 1)
    {
        return num;
    }
    int temp = 0;
    asm( "shll $1, %0 \n\t" : "=r"(temp) : "0"(num));
    return temp;
}
```

Note that `gcc` puts the operands into registers if you ask for it using the `r` constraint so really no reason to `mov` them yourself (at least in this small sample).
Also, I have used `0` in the input constraint to signal that it should be the same register as the output, because that's how `shl` works.

Still not sure about the `num == 1` condition, but presumably that's because we don't know the actual function of the complete function.